# Why can't I call method from event listener but can elsewhere in class?

Tags: java, oop, javafx, event-listener

I have the following code in a controller class in for a JavaFX GUI that provides an event listener for a combo box:

```
courseComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
                .addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(
                            ObservableValue<? extends String> selected,
                            String oldValue, String newValue) {

                           // Do stuff

    }
});
```

However, when I try to call another method from within it I am unable to:

```
courseComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
                    .addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void changed(
                                ObservableValue<? extends String> selected,
                                String oldValue, String newValue) {

                                this.setClassList(courseProcessed);

                               // Do Stuff

   }
});
```

I can call the method elsewhere in the class, though. More specifically, I can call it inside the `initialize()` function in my controller that this listener also resides in. Why am I having this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `this` within the listener refers to the listener current instance, not to the controller instance. To refer to the container instance, use the syntax `ControllerClassName.this`.

Comment: What are the pros and cons of doings as you suggest with `ControllerClassName.this` vs just the function name, as suggested in the other answer?

Comment: The difference is that if by chance the listner does have a method with the same name, that would be called.

Comment: What if `ChangeListener` had a `setClassList` method, you didn't know about? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is:

```
new ChangeListener<String>() {
   @Override
   public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> selected, String oldValue, String newValue) {
       this.setClassList(courseProcessed);// `this` refers to the current instance of the anonymous class `ChangeListener`
   }
}
```

In this anonymous class `ChangeListener` there is no method named `setClassList()` so the compiler complaints about it. You could try simply avoid using `this` keyword:

```
setClassList(courseProcessed);
```

OR

You could also try this:

```
YourClass.this.setClassList(courseProcessed);
```